# Image button events

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have the following code, which should give an alert message when an image button is clicked. But I am unable to execute it properly. Please help me to rectify my mistake!

```
<td>
   <input type="image" src="1.png" onclick="click()">
</td>
```

JavaScript:

```
function click () { 
    alert("hello"); 
}
```

Comment: Please show your `click()` function.

Comment: what about the javascript code ?

Comment: function click()
{
 alert("hello");
}

Comment: This looks OK. When the input is clicked, it should execute the `click` function. Please show more code.

Comment: It would be useful if you post the code of the function `click()`.

Comment: Actually, i was unable to write the JS code in the question, and it is above. It is working when i use, onload="click()" in the body tag, but not in the button tag

Comment: This is my JS
function click()
{
 alert("hello");
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of your function to something other than `click`

Comment: Hey, thanks. It's working. Should'nt we use those names like, click, load etc. .